# Substring formatting to get all characters after the first underscore but before the 2nd underscore?

Tags: c#, string, substring, delimiter

for example we have this string:

- hello_my name_is_bob

and want to get only the "my Name" portion of the string, how could I get this simply with substring?

Also, the format in the example will always be the same so I just need to retrieve what is after the first underscore but before the 2nd underscore.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) will do for this, no need to go into `Substring`:

```
var parts = "hello_my name_is_bob".Split('_');

string name = parts[1] // == "my name";
```

Or, in a one liner (though I find this less readable):

```
string name = "hello_my name_is_bob".Split('_')[1];
```

Comment: Good stuff, at first I was using double quotes but it was giving me an exception so I changed it to single quotes and it worked like a champ.

Comment: @MDL - Double quotes in C# delimit strings, single quotes delimit characters.

Answer (score 2):

```
"hello_my name_is_bob".Split('_').Skip(1).First();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know for sure that you have two underscores, use this code:

```
var pos = str.IndexOf('_');
var last = str.IndexOf('_', pos+1);
var res = str.Substring(pos+1, last-pos-1);
```

This will fail if the number of underscores is less than two.